Snowflake sproc for handling dynamic files


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table_from_csv(file_name STRING, target_table STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    // Step 1: Create a temporary table to get the CSV structure
    snowflake.execute(`CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
                       SELECT * FROM @csv_file_stage/` + file_name + `
                       FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = 'csv_format')
                       LIMIT 1;`);

    // Step 2: Generate the CREATE TABLE statement based on the temp table structure
    var createTableSQL = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: `SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' || :target_table || ' (' || 
                         LISTAGG(column_definition, ', ') || 
                         ');'
                  FROM (
                      SELECT COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE AS column_definition
                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEMP_TABLE'
                      ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                  )`,
        binds: { target_table: target_table }
    }).getSingleRow()[0];

    // Execute the CREATE TABLE statement
    snowflake.execute(createTableSQL);

    // Step 3: Load data from the CSV file into the target table
    snowflake.execute(`COPY INTO ` + target_table + `
                       FROM @csv_file_stage/` + file_name + `
                       FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = 'csv_format');`);

    return 'Table ' + target_table + ' created and data loaded successfully from ' + file_name;
$$;

CALL create_table_from_csv('file_name','target_table')



Have a need to build an sproc in Snowflake in order to adjust columns in the DB table based on the file that is in the external stage and it's loaded into a final table. Need to compare columns in case there are more columns or less columns in the .csv then the table need the table to be updated with the columns and loaded the data.
Thanks
Andy
Tried to build it but was getting the following error even though all the columns are text.
Error: SQL compilation error:
Unsupported data type 'O'.

Please update your question with the code for the SP - as editable text, appropriately formatted

Ok - so work which statement is giving the error, have a look at the actual statement being executed and you should be able to work out what the issue is. If you’re still struggling then update your question with the actual SQL statement giving the error (if it’s not the create table statement then include that at as well)
